# Python 3 doesn't have the file function

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, deprecated

In python 2.7 I was able to do:

```
file('text.txt', 'w').write('some text')
```

But in python 3 I have to use the open function, so I cannot write to a file on a single line anymore.

```
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
print('some text', file = f)
f.close()
```

Why did they remove the `file` function?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
open('text.txt', 'w').write('some text')
```

works the same way and `open` has been the canonical way to open a file (and hence create a `file` instance) for a long time, even on Python 2.x.

It should be noted, though, that in Python 3.8+ this now generates a `ResourceWarning` about an unclosed file. This is because, although the file will *typically* be closed automatically after the `write` call, depending on garbage-collection settings this will not *necessarily* happen immediately, so the open file handle may persist.  The proper way to ensure file closure and avoid the warning (and annoyingly, this makes the code no longer inline-able) is:

```
with open('text.txt', 'w') as fileHandle:
    fileHandle.write('some text')
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, `open` has been preferred over `file` since Python 2.5 (source: https://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/built-in-funcs.html ). Python 2.5 was released in September, 2006. That's over eight years ago.