# name 'file' is not defined. while running a XBRL code

Tags: python, package, finance, xbrl

`from xbrl import XBRLParser, GAAP, GAAPSerializer`

`import bs4, lxml`

`xbrl = xbrl_parser.parseGAAP(file(r"C:\Users\anant\NETRA\https---archives.nseindia.com-corporate-xbrl-INDAS_90168_794349_14022023041135.xml.url"))`

here I am trying to use a python-xbrl package. the error of "name 'file' is not defined" is showing up.

please guide me, resolving this issue.

Comment: Please familiarise yourself with the Stack Overflow guidelines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular:  "search and research" - pasting this error message into a search engine will give you the answer to your question.  "spelling, grammar and punctuation are important" - please capitalise sentences.  Also, please include the _full_ error message that you receive.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to run Python 2 code in Python 3.  See
[Python 3 doesn't have the file function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28121163/python-3-doesnt-have-the-file-function).

As a more general point, it looks like you're trying to read non-US-GAAP XBRL.  The `python-xbrl` library is not a general purpose XBRL processor, and is unlikely to work with XBRL from other sources.  I would recommend looking at using a different XBRL processor, such as [Arelle](https://www.arelle.org).